# Explicitly import Vue filters into component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-filter

I have a global filters file, and I am trying to explicitly import just one filter into a component.

In my filters file, I have:

```
//filters.js
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.filter('shorten', (str, len) => (str.length > len ? `${str.substring(0, len)}...` : str));
Vue.filter('secToMin', (dur) => Math.ceil (dur / 60));
```

and then in my component, I'd like to do something like:

```
//MyComponent.vue
import secToMin from './util/filters.js';
export default {
 filters: {
   secToMin: { secToMin, },
 },
};
```

But this does not actually fire the filters. Is it possible to do something like this??

Comment: It doesn't look like the filters file actually exports anything, it just registers the filters globally with Vue. Why do you want to register a filter locally if it is already registered globally?

Comment: The thought was that these filters might need to be accessible in other components, and this was to avoid having to rewrite that functionality elsewhere.

Comment: So are you saying that you no longer want to register these filters globally and you would like to import them locally on an individual basis instead?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the filters as named exports:

```js
export function shorten (str, len) {
  return str.length > len ? `${str.substring(0, len)}...` : str;
}

export function secToMin (dur) {
  return Math.ceil(dur / 60);
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
import { secToMin } from './util/filters.js';

export default {
 filters: {
   secToMin
 }
};
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!! I thought I was limited to having to use Vue.filter. Thank you!

Comment: @bjorkland Using `Vue.filter` is for registering global filters. It is directly analogous to `Vue.component` or `Vue.directive`. There's no need to use any of these functions if you just need the filter/component/directive locally on an individual component.